# How does `read` saves the output in the `$REPLY` variable

Tags: bash

I wonder why I can't read the line from output of pipe. The following is my command:

```
find / -name sysinit.target 2> /dev/null | head -n1 | read
```

I expected to find the line read from the output of `head` to be recorded in the system variable `$REPLY`, yet there is nothing in that variable. Why is the line output by `head` not recorded by `read` in the variable `$REPLY`?

Comment: This is also the subject of [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: `head -n1` is also fairly unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn'r work because the pipeline is run in a subshell. Take a look at the `lastpipe`  shell option to work around it or just use process substitution.

```
read < <(...)
```

Also as a suggestion maybe use `IFS=` and `-r`.